# Check if the data is updated

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've made a working chat with meteor and mongodb, but I want to play a sound or something when there is a new message. However, I don't know how to check if data is updated. I could check if there is a new message by counting the messages before and after the update, but I just don't know how to check for an update.

So my question here is: **How do I check for an update in the data?**

Comment: If you are talking about the update in the database, you can attach hooks to the mongodb. https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks Consequently, you can use sockets to connect db updates with the client updates (the sound, new message icon etc.)
I wouldn't advise you to use db hooks for that. As one of the alternatives you can use is XMPP to send and receive messages. However there are lots of alternatives as well. 
P.S: Not really familiar with Meteor, hence not posting this as an asnwer

Comment: create `observer` for your database collection.`http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe`

Comment: Yes, the above is the straightforward "Meteor" way to do it. Create a client side observer to respond each time a chat is added or changes (depending on your implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a website that needs to pop up a toastr alert whenever a new message arrives. My collection is called "Alerts". This is what I do:

```
 Alerts.find({notified: false}).observeChanges({
    added: function(id, doc) {
        Alerts.update(id, {
            $set: {
                notified: true
            }
        });
        toastr.info(foo, bar);
    }
 });
```

Whenever a new alert is created whose field "notified" is false, a toastr alert will be created and that alert will be marked as "notified: true".

Alternatively you could do the same thing but create a separate collection of "notifications" that when observed, are removed from the collection as well that are a distinct collection from your chat messages collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create [a tailing cursor on the oplog collection](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters), so you get a new document whenever something (anything!) in the database changes. But that's not really an elegant solution, because that handler would need to process a lot of junk.

It might be better to have the routine which writes the message to the database also inform any currently online users. There is really no good reason to go the detour over the database.